# .NET Globalization/Localization Solutions

Tags: .net, winforms, localization, globalization

What are some quality third-party software solutions for managing localization in a .NET Windows Forms app? Currently the only one I know of is [Lingobit](http://www.lingobit.com/index.html) but I don't have any idea of if it's any good and if there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three great ones:

1. [ResxCrunch](http://resxcrunch.com/)
2. [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html)
3. ResourceStudio (not yet released)

Zeta is the most polished and allows for active translations of resource strings. I am developing ResourceStudio that will be an all singing and dancing localisation tool that will eventually cover all platforms - this won;t be ready for a while yet though (spare time job).

I hope this helps.

---

*Note. the ones I have linked are FREE. there is no doubt that Lingobit is a more substantive product. If you don't like the 600+ USD price tag then the above might help you...*

Comment: The more substantive the better, money is not an issue in my case because my company would cover the expense.

Comment: Then the above are probably not for you. I have looked into this for ages myself having recently localised a large WinForms application. The above are by far the best free options, but I don't think you will get better that the package you have already referenced in this case. You only have to look at the companies that uses the software to see that this software is well respected... ]

Answer (score 1):

And one more for enterprise applications [LocServ](http://loc-serv.com/). It's free and you can use it right away.

Our team developed this tool for localization of our app with more then 2 million lines of code.

LocServ tracks all literals that need to be localized and lets you know the amount of work to be done.  You can export the fields that need localization and import them back after translation is done. In order to filter literals we created built-in support for simple rules and you can decide which literals don’t need the localization. Moreover, LocServ analyses literals and shows duplicates which helps to reduce costs for translation.

You can try LocStudio for free here http://loc-serv.com/